# firebase first call very slow on IOS

Tags: firebase, ionic2

the first call to firebase is very slow > 10 seconds, and some Network error happend. I forked the repo to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/frankpolkm/ionic-conference-app

It simply added firebase to the driftyco/ionic-conference-app demo app. Please have a look at the code change in https://github.com/frankpolkm/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/app/app.ts

and here is the console log. There has no NetWork Error before firebase added.

```
0     104436   log      DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER, 1308, ms
1     104725   log      Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
2     104842   time     signInAnonymously
3     105151   debug    swiper initEvents, attach
4     109567   warn     Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
5     109568   warn     Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required
6     110230   error    Error: Network Error, http://192.168.2.103:8100/build/js/zone.js, Line: 260
7     110230   error    Error: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred., http://192.168.2.103:8100/build/js/zone.js, Line: 260
8     115416   timeEnd  signInAnonymously
9     115416   log      signInAnonymously: 10574ms
10    115416   log      uid=mZevh2GdnyaNv1BSfnB78HC17di2
11    120419   error    Error: Network Error, http://192.168.2.103:8100/build/js/zone.js, Line: 260
12    120420   error    Error: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred., http://192.168.2.103:8100/build/js/zone.js, Line: 260
```

Please let me know what I did wrong.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/vxJfM-7oSsg

Answer (score 0):

Adding `<allow-navigation href="*" />` to the confix.xml File solved it for me.